# Cross-referencing object fields

Tags: ida, ida-plugin, idapython, struct

I'ld like to see which functions are operating with certain object's fields that I already processed, meaning I created the structure and assigned it to the correct places in the functions in IDA, without having to run a dynamic debugger. (for example, I would like to see a list of the functions accessing/writing/reading the *Foo* data field of the *Bar* object), but as far as I know it's not implemented in IDA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDA has been able to show [cross-references](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/592.shtml) to structure members since version 6.2:

[image: Structure member cross-references]

Comment: You need to have HexRays decompiler plugin for this, right?

Comment: No. Just regular IDA Pro. Hex-Rays isn't required.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this IDA feature doesn't always work as needed especially if you define your objects in Hex-Rays.

If your problem is around using Hex-Rays, you can use the [XRefs](https://github.com/EiNSTeiN-/hexrays-python-plugins/blob/master/xrefs/xrefs.py) plugin with the [hexrays-python](https://github.com/EiNSTeiN-/hexrays-python) API in IDA 6.4.

As far as I understand latest version of IDAPython with support of IDA 6.5 at
google code already contains these bindings in IDA API module, but it is not fully operational yet (at least I'm not succeeded to make it work).